# What is the .. css source showing up in Chrome Inspector when using Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4 (the Sass version) and most elements have styles applied to them that are coming from a source listed simply as `..`. When I click on it to see what it is I get the following:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

What is this source? Shouldn't everything be compiled into foundation.css?

Comment: **I think it must be a problem with your server.** Otherwise, could you provide us more details, like your source file ? As you said, everything should be compiled into one single file (it should be named app.css, or foundation.css). So your HTML should looks like this : <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css" /> And of course they should be "clickable".

Comment: I do have normalize.css and foundatoin.css, but I also have this weird .. source. When I hover over it, it shows the path to where it supposedly is, which is just inside my css directory. I suspect it might have something to do with Ruby/Compass. I failed to mention that I installed Foundation through Compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that whenever `..` shows up in Inspector the line number shown matches that of thee selector in the .scss file. I have no idea how this works, or what exactly is responsible for this.

Oh! Just figured it out! It was the experimental SASS support feature which I had enabled in Chrome!

Mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server: If you put an image (foo.jpg) in your directory, can you open it and see it in your browser? I don't have enough details to help you (OS, server, ...) but you probably need to look this way. If the file aren't opening, you have problems in your server config or file permission!

(@admins : sorry, it should be a comment but it seems I don't have sufficient rep to reply to the comment)